# Different ValueError for the same operation in List and Tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

I am curious why ValueErrors are different in List and Tuple when I try to get an index.  ValueError of a list returns in well format with actual argument "ValueError: 'ITEM' is not in list", whereas tuple returns something like this "ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple". 
I think List and Tuple both are calling same index() method then why it is raising different ValueErrors?

```
>>> jframe_li
['Angular', 'React', 'Vue.js', 'Ember.js', 'Mereor', 'Node.js', 'Backbone.js']
>>> jframe_tu
('Angular', 'React', 'Vue.js', 'Ember.js', 'Mereor', 'Node.js', 'Backbone.js')
>>> jframe_li.index('React')
1
>>> jframe_tu.index('React')
1
>>> jframe_li.index('react')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 'react' is not in list

>>> jframe_tu.index('react')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple
```

Comment: @snakecharmerb According to docs, Tuples implement all of the common sequence operations which include `.index`, now would you say it implements it in a different way?

Comment: Yeah, you were right, I also learned in the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are implementation differences in the `index` methods for lists and tuples, including in the text of a raised `ValueError`.

See [ValueError string for tuple.index](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/tupleobject.c#L557) and [ValueError string for list.index](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L2506)